# setAsync returns success status but not inserting data with CoercionType.text in Outlook on the web

Tags: javascript, outlook, add-in, outlook-web-addins

I am creating an Outlook add-in. In Compose Mode inserting text with CoercionType=text does not work in the current Office on the web. The mail body is not changed!

Inserting HTML formatted text with CoercionType=html is okay. 
With Exchange 2016 inserting text in CoercionType=text is okay.

Code:

```js
text = "some dummy text";
var options = { coercionType: CoercionType.Text };

Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(text, options, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

the result says "succeded"!

Is that a bug? Are there any bytes needed to close the message on Outlook on the web? (EOF, Null-Byte)?

Thx
Moritz

Comment: We are not able to reproduce the issue reported. No EOF/Null character is required. Can you check whether there is any javascript error on console?

Comment: Hi, there is no JavaScript error in console. The problem is only in Outlook.office.com (Exchange 2019?), compose mail, mail Options "switch to plain text". With Option "switch to plain text" neither Coercion.Type="html" nor CoercionType."text" will work. The message body will not be changed, the call returns with "succeded!".

Comment: We are able to reproduce this issue now. Thanks for reporting this bug. It has been put into our backlog, but unfortunately, we don't have timelines to share at this point.